# Method "getParam" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()

Tags: php, zend-framework, ubuntu

I have moved my project files to another server, and now i'm getting this in all my pages, it's like i have missed some config, does anyone know what can i do?
I'm using Zend Framework 1.11.11 !
Which informations did you need?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using.?

Comment: how to know what are you doing wrong without any code '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED! I was using a different framework version! All my code was in 1.12, and i had configured 1.11.